# Apache doesn't work with multiple websites in the www folder

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, webserver, virtual-host

I have configured apache on my home web server; so far I have only run one website on it and it has worked flawlessly: I simply typed my hostname in a browser and my local website would show up.

Now I need to run multiple websites, so I have created multiple subdirectories in the `/var/www` folder. I would like to continue accessing them typing my hostname followed by a `/` and then the name of the subfolder. I have tried configuring different virtual hosts, adding these lines of code to each virtual host:

```
ServerName hostname/site1
DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
```

but whenever I type `hostname/site1` I get the apache error page and not the home page of `site1`.

Is there some other configuration line that I have missed?

**Update**

I have removed the new configuration lines and I have brought the configuration files to their default state, since this should work automatically without any particular configuration. I still can't access the subfolders by typing `hostname/site1` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) directive is only meant to contain a hostname and a port.  A slash to a subdirectory is not part of a hostname.

In your example, I assume you might have something at `/var/www/site2` as well as `/var/www/site1`.  For that implementation, you would want to have:

```
ServerName hostname
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Then you could access `http://hostname/site1` and `http://hostname/site2`

To get subdomains, you'll probably want to look into [Name-based Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).  Generally, this involves things like subdomain.hostname, i.e. test.example.org which might point to /var/wwwtest and prod.example.org that could be at /var/wwwprod. Generally you would ensure that the subdomains are in in different paths so that you can't get to one site from the other.

This previous question has a sample implementation: [Configure Apache to serve multiple subdomains via HTTP + HTTPS](https://superuser.com/questions/241315/configure-apache-to-serve-multiple-subdomains-via-http-https?rq=1)

Comment: I was somehow expecting that the ServerName directory only worked with hostname+port. Anyway, I know that the way I set it up, it should work with no specific configuration, but if I visit `hostname/site1` I still get apache's page not found error.

Comment: Does just visiting `hostname` work?  If so, what are the permissions on `/var/www/site1`?  Your web server user (likely apache) will need at least read permissions.

Comment: Visiting `hostname` stopped working as soon as I added subfolders. Before that it worked. Permissions are `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: You're saying Apache stopped working after you added subdirectories in your DocumentRoot?  That doesn't make any sense - that means anyone who adds content to a website would be breaking apache whenever they made subdirectories.  What's more likely is that you modified your conf files, created an error in them, and when you restarted Apache, things broke.  Either restore a known good conf file, or try to figure out where the error is in your conf files.

Comment: I'm not saying that, I am saying that if I visit `hostname/site1` I don't see anything, but if I put those contents into `/var/www` and point my browser to `hostname`, I see the website

Comment: What did you mean when you say "Visiting hostname stopped working as soon as I added subfolders."?  What happens when you go to hostname/site1?  What if you try to directly access something i.e. hostname/site1/file.html Does the error.log show anything?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual hosts are only useful when setting up multiple domain names (or subdomains). Here you want to access your websites to the same adress, you probably want to set up `Alias` instead. Moreover, if your webserver root folder points at `/var/www`, you have no configuration to do : just putting your web pages in subdirectory, for exemple `drupal` should let them being accessed by `your.domain.name/drupal`

Comment: The specific configuration for this is `ServerAlias www.domain2.com` and so forth, one per line.

Comment: I tried that too, but I still get apache's page not found error.